# For iOS development, is it better to adjust content in one MVC, or create multiple MVC's?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, model-view-controller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm working on an iOS app with a Split View Controller that has a series of buttons in the master view. Each button will change the contents of the detail view, but all of the various detail views will share the same layout. Being pretty new to Swift, I originally intended to create one MVC for the Detail and adjust it's contents based on which button is pressed, but it seems that if I created a unique MVC for each I could do the whole thing with no actual coding at all.

Making multiple MVC's seems inefficient to me, but using the IB when possible seems to be the way to go in most instances. I'm sure I'm not the first person to wonder this, but I'm using the wrong nomenclature on searches or maybe I'm just missing something obvious. Any thoughts or links?

Comment: There is no "Best Practice" when it comes to choosing IB over code or vice versa. It is all based on your preferences and comforts. If you do not have any IBActions or other functions in your various Details, and the only thing you have to do is to modify a few UI objects, I would suggest re-using the same View Controller and writing the code out for the modifications. If you have any UI elements that have connected functions (IBAction/GestureRecognizer) and the resulting actions are different, I would recommend using different ViewControllers. It's just easier to manage the program flow then.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Tcharni.

Comment: Multiple view controllers seems onerous at first, but in the long run, I have found that it makes maintaining and extending the app much easier. You have more view controllers, but each one will be simpler than one do-everything VC.

Comment: Thanks @DanLoughney, I'm glad I asked this because I was heading in the other direction but I'm getting now that more MVC's means more encapsulation/balkanization so that's what it'll be in this instance. It's crazy how little coding actually has to be done in this system.

Comment: A single section in an app, for lets say, inviting friends, will require me around 20 view controllers, and over 15 navigation controllers. This is because it's best to split it all up, make everything it's own little workhorse,  and then move from there. If you need to gut a section, you just strip that file and disconnect the single import line of code or any other simple calls. It's actually just a 3-4 hour process to produce a 30-50 file processs like this once you get use to it, and it will make your life infinitely easier than the huge VC

Comment: You need to understand then implement view controller hierarchy. You will be thankful - it takes longer to develop and understand - but the learning is lifelong and once you have it you will be capable of so easily updating your views and apps. I have developed a three layered view controller hierarchy and it makes my life easy. Unfortunately I had to learn the hard way and you might need to also. Build it simply at first and with great expanse and no care, then reduce it down to the essential elements at each hierarchical layer. Best way to learn.